# Cannot generate Id using Data annotation (EF6)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm new at EF6 and Asp.net MVC5. 
There's problem of generating a unique ID automatically when I try to create my entities using the code first approach.

Consider an entity like this:

```
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100), MinLength(5)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

When I put `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` on PostId or even remove it. I was always get an exception error like this:

> “Cannot insert the value NULL into column ‘PostId'”.
>   “column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I don't know why EF6's always try to insert a null value to the Id column.

Then later, I found a solution.
I changed

`DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` to `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`

and the problem was solved.

However, this solution doesn't seem to work like I expected.
the values inserted to the column are always the same. It's not unique.

With EF core, everything is just simple, I don't need `DatabaseGenerated`,just leave it to convention. But with EF6, I'm stuck. What I want is the Id field must be unique and increase everytime it inserted to the database.

Can someone please help me this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to EF also, but I just create an Id field and it is inserted automatically by SQL Server, such as this model in my current project.  The Id field populates as expected when I add new rows:

```
public class BlogPosts
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ShortPost { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Post { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what's version of EF did you use ? EF6 or EF core? I've tried this with EF6, but still get the error.

Comment: I'm using version 6.2

Answer (score 0):

When you apply `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` to your key property you are telling EF that the database will generate the identity. From the error it sounds like your database PostId column is not configured as an identity or primary key.

If you manually created the table and columns in the database you should ensure the configuration is at least compatible, or you should use migrations to ensure the database is configured in a good state for your EF model.